# creating chart description when using mfrow

Tags: r, axis-labels

I want to create a description for the group of images. It is to appear at the bottom of the page (between the yellow and green plots) and if the text is more than one row long, it is to be left aligned.

The basic script I have does not create the desired label.

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2), oma = c(1, 0, 0, 0))
#oma creates more space at bottom of graph

# create your four plots and labels
hist(mtcars$mpg, breaks=12, col="red")
mtext("a)",side=3, at=8,2)
hist(mtcars$mpg, breaks=12, col="blue")
mtext("b)",side=3, at=8,2)
hist(mtcars$mpg, breaks=12, col="yellow")
mtext("c)",side=3, at=8,2)
hist(mtcars$mpg, breaks=12, col="green") 
mtext("d)",side=3, at=8,2)

# create label
mtext('Figure 1. The same historgrams of mpg plotted with different colours. Clockwise from upper left: red, blue, green, yellow', 
      side = 1, outer = TRUE, line = 2)
```

Comment: With a bottom `oma` of 1, the text at `line = 2` is ends up outside the plotting region. Either (a) increase bottom `oma`, or (b) decrease `line`. For left adjustment, readthefantasticmanual.